Frequent Crashes in internshrstr after Multiple Executions of Lua Script Using lua_newthread
I have a question regarding the usage of lua_newthread. After creating a coroutine using lua_newthread, I use luaL_loadfile to load a script file. The script executes successfully multiple times, but it tends to crash around the 40th to 50th execution, specifically in the internshrstr function.
I'm not sure if there is a flaw in my usage of threads. Could someone help me understand this issue?
static VOID __msg_exe_script_cb(IN message *msg)
{
    int rt = 0;
    SCRIPT_EXE_NODE_S *exe_node = (SCRIPT_EXE_NODE_S *)msg->pMsgData;
    if (!exe_node){
        print("path is null.");
        return;
    }

    if (!exe_node->co && !exe_node->path){
        print("co and path is null.");
        goto ERR_EXIT;
    }

    if (!exe_node->co){
        exe_node->co = lua_newthread(lua_mgr_s.L);
        if (!exe_node->co){
            print("new co is null.");
            goto ERR_EXIT;    
        }
        
        print("load file:%s.",exe_node->path);

        if (luaL_loadfile(exe_node->co, exe_node->path) != LUA_OK) {
            print("error loading script: %s", lua_tostring(exe_node->co, -1));
            lua_pop(exe_node->co, 1);
            goto ERR_EXIT;    
        }
    }

    INT_T status = lua_resume(exe_node->co, NULL, 0);
    if (LUA_OK == status){
        print("script finished.");
        lua_pop(exe_node->co, 1); 
    }else if (LUA_YIELD == status){
        print("script coroutine.");
        return;
    }else {
        print("error running script: %s", lua_tostring(exe_node->co, -1));
        lua_pop(exe_node->co, 1);
    }
    

    return;
}


I have tried to forcefully collect garbage using lua_gc(lua_mgr_s.L, LUA_GCCOLLECT, 0); to reclaim related state machine resources, but it has not been effective.

You've never popped the created thread.
